# silverlight-4.0 INotifyDataErrorInfo with Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0 with Silverlight 4.0. I wanted to validate my Entity using INotifyDataErrorInfo. For that do I need to create duplicate class on clientside and implement INotifyDataErrorInfo ? I can not Implement it  on  autogenerated Entity as entity gets updated when my datasource changes. So How should I do with this ?

Comment: Are you using RIA services? If so you can extend the validation using a custom validator marked up on the services metadata objects (that will work on server and/or on client).

Comment: You can subscribe to the datasource changed event and update validation on the UI using the ErrorsChanged event

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is Silverlight only:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx

you will have to create separate properties and validate those.